# Bootstrap controls in one line

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to use text box with a glyphicon in one straight line, here what I've done:

http://plnkr.co/edit/GZQeGTqDsvTh9XsXmMFy?p=preview

```
  <div class="w3-row" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <div class="w3-col s6">
            <input ng-readonly="true" type="text" ng-model="login" placeholder="Login" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col s4">
            <input class="form-control" ng-readonly="true" type="text" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="w3-col s2">
            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh btn btn-default"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

It looks alright, but the glyph button is slightly below than the bottom line of text inputs, I want its height to be stretched to those inputs, or, at least, to be in the middle relatively to their center, then it will be good looking.

Please help me find the solution.

Notice:

1. Either w3.css or angular-ui's bootstrap can be used to solve this issue.
2. The solution **should not depend on using the "form-inline"**.
3. The best solution would be the one which doesn't use "row" "col" classes whatsoever, because they make it impossible to stretch line horizontally to 100% and fill each column without making it look ugly!

Thank you.

Comment: Your main problem is because the glyphicon should be in a span inside the button. The 'form-inline' class doesn't have to be attached to a form. It can jut be attached to a div within a form, turning part of the form into an inline format. You can also use bootstrap input-group to visually group the button with the input. See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GFvEmfAGac5kb7MwcKl2?p=preview) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your button markup to this

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh "></span>
</button>
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3nYdMmGRrb23XhySjPT?p=preview)

Comment: I just separated the `button` style from the `glyphicon` style, it's how I've seen a lot of people do and it seems logical to have such a separation.
My guess is some css rule collision.